# Can I have a field that combines multiple MySQL columns into one array in a Laravel Model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am currently trying to construct a Laravel model based on a list of courses and course sections. For each record in the Course Sections database table, there are 7 columns for each day of the week that it might be on.

```
CourseID|SectionNumber|...|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun|
-------------------------------------------------------
  1001  |      01     |...|Mon| 0 |Wed| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
```

Admittedly, it's not the best designed database (it should probably be booleans, and would also probably make sense as a relations table rather than in the same large table) but I don't have direct control over that part.

But what I would like to do is have all of those days stored in an array under one value `$days` in the Course model, however I'm not quite sure where to go about it. My end goal is to be able to Serialize a CourseSection Model into a JSON feed.

```
$course->days;
//should return [Mon, Wed]
```

Right now, in my **CourseController**, I have the following code that constructs that array as it feeds it to the View based off of a raw query

```
$days = array_where([$result->isMon, $result->isTue, $result->isWed, $result->isThu, $result->isFri, $result->isSat, $result->isSun], 
                       function ($key, $value)
    {
        return $value != "0";
    });

$courses[$course_key]['sections'][$result->section_number]->days = $days;
```

I suppose my question is can I do this all in one model? Is it possible to have variables equal an array? Or should this stay in the Controller and have the Model as a direct representation of the structure in the database?

Comment: I'd make that an attribute on the model and then append it to the appends - that way, you always have it available on the course. For documentation, see here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Accessors and Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) to append extra data to your Eloquent models.

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Course extends Eloquent
{
    protected $appends = ['days'];

    public function getDaysAttribute()
    {
        $values = [];
        // Build your array of data from your existing database structure here...
        return $values;
    }
}
```

You can then refer to this new item without additional work in your controllers:

```
$course = Course::find(1);
$array = $course->days; // This value will come from the getDaysAttribute() value in the Eloquent model
```

**Note:** I haven't tested this code, but I've taken it from one of my projects built in Laravel 5.1 which utilises these methods. I haven't written the code for generating the `$values` array, but you should be able to put that together based on your existing code.

---

Alternatively, if you wanted to modify your database structure, you could look at using [Array Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) which would automatically serialise/deserialise an array for storing as text in the database.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Course extends Model {

    public $appends = ['days'];

    public function getDaysAttribute(){

        $days = ['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun'];
        $course = this;
        return array_where($days,function($key, $val) use ($course)){
            return $course[$value] != 0;
        }

    }

}
```

Then you can use `$course->days`, and when you serialize to JSON the `days` attribute will be included courtesy of the `appends` attribute.